# How to write an C/C++ application that writes to a /var/log/myapp directory?

Tags: c++, linux, logging, c++11, user-defined-literals

**Background**

On Linux systems, [Application Logs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LinuxLogFiles#Application_Logs) exist in subdirectories of `/var/log`, which is owned by `root/root` and has 755 permissions on my system.  For example, I see `/var/log/mysql` and `/var/log/samba`.

**Question**

If I want a **myapp** to be able to write into a `/var/log/myapp`, what is the *canonical way* of accomplishing this in C/C++?

**Thoughts**

Do I have to do something crazy like `setuid root` if I don't want to `sudo a_setup_script.sh`?  Note that I am aware of the `syslog` routines, but they are insufficient for my needs (I need to log much more information, separated into different files, hence the need for the subdirectory).

Do I need to look into a combination of Ubuntu packaging (to set up the directory) and direct file IO into the subdirectory (by **myapp**)?

I would like to follow standards as much as possible.

**Addendum**

I forgot to mention, **myapp** is actually a daemon processes (a server that listens to clients) so it wouldn't be so bad to have a **myapp_user** which actually runs/starts the process.

**ANSWER**

For Ubuntu, the best solution appears to be `rsyslog`, a powerful, modern replacement for `syslog`.  It will generate files/directories as necessary, it has a built-in language for flexible routing of `syslog` entries, and it uses the simple, old `syslog` API at the C/C++ level.  To store routing information, you can define your own encoding of the text message in C/C++, in conjunction with a proper `rsyslog.conf` to handle the decoding.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, no no no. No suid for such stuff. These logs are managed by a process known as "syslog" and there is an API to send messages to this logger:

```
   void openlog(const char *ident, int option, int facility);
   void syslog(int priority, const char *format, ...);
   void closelog(void);
```

Or you can type 'man syslog' on the command line and get all the info :-)

Update: you will need permissions to edit syslog's configuration file to send message to a separate log file, otherwise they will end up in the default location (probably /var/log/syslog).

Comment: are you sure you can use this with subdirectories?  read my OP carefully - if I dump all my stuff into `/var/log/syslog`, it would render that file useless (there is so much stuff).

Comment: @kfmfe04 Yes. Please check the update. You will need to configure syslog to send _your_ messages to _your_ file. For example:   `news.crit                       /var/log/news/news.crit  
news.err                        /var/log/news/news.err`

Comment: @kfmfe04 sorry for multiple edits. Comments are a bit painful. :(

Comment: +1 ty - ok - I think I can dig into the API for that - for the setup, is there an API that will handle subdirectory creation, too?  Looking at the headers, I see something like LOG_LOCAL0, and LOG_LOCAL1 (maybe for user defined apps).  I will google a bit more... (but your answer is good enough to point me in the right direction - ty).

Comment: @kfmfe04 you need to create subdirectory in advance. And then add configuration to syslog's config file for one of the 'local' facilities to send output to the file of your choice. Sort of `local0.* /var/log/myapp/myapp.log` and then just use `openlog` with `LOG_LOCAL0`.

Comment: ty for the details - it looks like `rsyslogd` is the new standard on Ubuntu - I will look into how to configure/run it - looks advanced http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/manual.html